# How to implement a BigRational power method

Tags: c#, numerics

I'm usning the BCL Codeplex implementation of `BigRational`, however it doesn't seem to have a Pow method that can take two `BigRational`, only one that takes a `BigRational` and a `BigInteger`. I'd write one myself, but I have no idea where to start. 
EDIT: Some code:

```
        public static BigRational Pow(BigRational baseVal, BigRational exponent, int inputPrecision)
    {
        if (exponent == 0)
        {
            return BigRational.One;
        }
        if (exponent == 1)
        {
            return baseVal;
        }
        if (exponent.GetWholePart() == exponent)
        {
            return Pow(baseVal, exponent.GetWholePart());
        }
        baseVal = Round(baseVal, inputPrecision); //custom rounding method
        exponent = Round(exponent, inputPrecision); 
        BigInteger exponentWhole = exponent.GetWholePart();
        BigRational extra = exponent - exponentWhole;
        return //what?
    }
```

Comment: The rational numbers aren't closed under exponentiation, e.g. 2^(1/2) is irrational.

Comment: The question is essentially "I don't know how to do something impossible" -- assuming that you want the result to be a BigRational of course. Since by definition no one knows how to do something impossible, I don't think you're going to get any answers. If you want to implement a Pow that returns something else then clarify the question.

Comment: For example, you could write an implementation of Pow that returned a *sequence* of BigRationals, with the property that each subsequent member was *closer* to the result in reals. The user could then iterate that sequence until the difference between successive members was guaranteed to be always less than a given epsilon. Is that sufficient for your purposes?  The math to do so is not particularly difficult.

Comment: Don't mind passing a parameter for precision.